# How to fix incompatible types when type parameter is used as both property type and constructor argument type?

Tags: typescript

I have a base class with a generic type:

```
class Base<O> {
  value: O

  constructor (input: O) {
    // do stuff with `input`
    this.value = input
  }
}
```

Other classes extend it:

```
interface FooValue {
  color: string
}

class Foo extends Base<FooValue> {
  action () {
    console.log(this.value.color) // this.value correctly has type FooValue
  }
}
```

And I have a list of classes that extend the base class:

```
interface ClassList {
  [index: string]: typeof Base
}

let list: ClassList = {
  foo: Foo
}
```

But I get an error at `foo: Foo`:

```
(property) foo: typeof Foo
Type 'typeof Foo' is not assignable to type 'typeof Base'.
  Types of parameters 'input' and 'input' are incompatible.
    Type 'O' is not assignable to type 'FooValue'.
```

Check this [in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMA8B5AfNA3gWAFDWgDcwQBXBALmhTzwOAHsA7CAFwCdThWH3oAKAJZMADqVZUUASix0C0VgAtBEAHTEyCaAF5owsazkBfPCdx5hrBOwBmYYFoBiDBgDUS5WfmiMQvKmzswgDmprS4oJAwzgzQCAAeVkwAJjDwEMgx7poYON72rILMAjJ58j7MEAwgCKp+wfxKKuoetb68UsZh5riW1nYO0ADC4FAAMiqsXgQA2sLJCQEcIQC6VKwAniIIDDZwiN14NVMgk1QjURNsOtPQNi5UMaZAA). Why does that happen? `O` is the type parameter and it is set to `FooValue`, which is the requested type.

## Edit

To clarify, I want the class list to hold class *constructors*. That list is exported and then you can do:

```
import list from 'module'

let Ctor = list.foo
let foo = new Foo({ color: 'red' })
foo.action() // red
```

Basically, I want `ClassList` to be an object that is allowed to contain only a reference to the `Base` constructor or the constructor of a class that extends `Base`. Like this:

```
let list: ClassList = {
  foo: Foo   // ok
  bar: Base  // ok
  arr: Array // error
}
```

In my application, those classes are imported from various places and I want to ensure they are extending one common class that I care about.

Comment: If you rated my answer down, could you provide more information as to what you're trying to do? foo: Foo won't work in your list variable since it's value not type.  I updated my answer. And if you want to be able to call action on foo, then it must be Foo, not Base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be stemming from legacy JavaScript days, but a "class" is not actually something tangible on its own. It's basically a function that constructs an object along with a prototype.

In your case you want to specify that `ClassList` enumerates such classes but in reality what it enumerates is such constructor functions. You can get this to work using something like:

```
class Base<O> {
  value: O

  constructor (input: O) {
    this.value = input
  }
}

interface FooValue {
  color: string
}

class Foo extends Base<FooValue> {
  action () {
    console.log(this.value.color)
  }
}

interface ClassList {
  [index: string]: new (...args: any[]) => Base<any>;
}

let list: ClassList = {
  foo: Foo
}
```

Note the syntax to indicate that the values in `ClassList` are constructors returning any kind of `Base` object. Usually I would avoid using `any` but unfortunately this is the best way I could figure out. Perhaps someone with more TS knowledge than me can provide a better solution.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMA8B5AfNA3gWAFDWgDcwQBXBALmhTzwOAHsA7CAFwCdThWH3oAKAJZMADqVZUUASix0C0VgAtBEAHTEyCaAF5owsazkBfPCdx5hrBOwBmYYFoBiDBgDUS5WfmiMQvKmzswgDmprS4oJAwzgzQCAAeVkwAJjDwEMgx7poYON72rILMAjJ58j7MEAwgCKp+wfxKKuoetb68UsZh5hHgUHBgfAlJqQMZSEykALYARta5cgVFTCVe5Yws1bX1jcpqGuSd3mZmFkxWtvZaAMJ9EAAyKqxr0ADawskJARwhALpUTAQAHcBPpxFQwEwAJ4ybQYdLISFQtAAbm6eBqzxATyotyijzYOheNhcVBiABo5DNBlR4OxKd5qQAvKgAETAVlMQA)

Comment: Yep, that's correct, I care about the constructor functions only. What you proposed seems to do the job nicely, but I think that `new (...args: any[]) => Base<any>` is better because it supports multiple arguments in the constructors of subclasses.